# Converted my c++ mixed mode vs2008 project to vs2010, could not locate the assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, reference, clr

After I converted my vs2008 c++ mixed mode project to vs2010 I got this error.

warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly  "XYZ, Version=3.0.0.0,....

Vs2008 didn't care about correct version, is it okey to remove the version attribute from the reference in the project file(not possible from GUI, but seems to work if I edit in notepad)?
Or is there a better solution?

Now we need update the reference when we rebuild assembly XYZ.

```
<Reference Include="XYZ, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <HintPath>..\XYZ.dll</HintPath>
  <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>true</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Is it better to add this to the cpp file?

#using "..\XYZ.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "SpecificVersion" node, so that the reference looks like below:

```
<Reference Include="XYZ, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"> 
  <HintPath>..\XYZ.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>false</SpecificVersion>
  <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>true</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies> 
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly> 
</Reference>
```

Although it is not displayed on the vs2010 UI in the Property Pages, MSBuild seems to recognise this setting and accept any version of the referenced dll when it's set to false.